# behavioursubjects with array

Tags: angular, typescript

The output of the following is `[object object]`, instead of `[{a,b},{b,c}]`

```js
// service
bData : BehaviorSubject<any[]> =  new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

bDataSubject = this.bData.asObservable(); 

// component: 
 
data = [{a,b},{b,c}];
 
this.service.bData.next((this.data));
  
this.service.bData.subscribe(value =>
 console.log("value changed: " + value)
);
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Replace `console.log("value changed: " + value)` with `console.log("value changed: ", value)`. Notice the comma instead of the plus sign. The plus concatenates the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First name it properly:

```
bDataSubject: BehaviorSubject<any[]> =  new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
bData$ = this.bData.asObservable(); 

// to submit
bDataSubject.next(this.data);

// to consume
this.service.bData$.subscribe(value =>
 console.log("value changed: " + value)
);
```